# Multivariate time series with discontinuous data with multiple trends

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, multivariate-analysis

I want to build a time series prediction model (not forecasting),
I have 2 questions about training and testing of the same,
Q.1. How to train the model using discontinuous data(multiple trends)?

representative image attached- there are multiple gaps also in the data which I don't want to impute.

Q.2. Can I train my model using 1st trend and test on 2nd? eventually I want to use both trend for training and predict going forward, how can I do that?
This is a chemical process where 2nd trend shows the same process after restart of equipment.

I have tried modeling using arimax and nnetar but could only train and test on the same trend (training on 1st trend and testing on 2nd yielded very bad results)
Any clue or resource which deals with such problems will be useful.[image: timeseries trend]